# XSLT Multiple Child

Tags: xslt

I have an XML which has multiple child elements. Item Group will be only once and can have minimum or more Transactions for each Item_Entry. In other words, Item_Entry will have only one Item_Group, but can have one more more Transactions. I need to generate my output based on the transaction. My output should contain all the transactions for each item. I need some help with XSLT for this.

```
XML:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Item_Data>
<Item_Entry>
    <Item_group>
        <Item_Name>Name1</Item_Name>
        <Item_ID>0001</Item_ID>
        <Sale_Date>2019-01-01-00:00</Sale_Date>
    </Item_group>
    <Transaction>
        <TxnCode Description="Store1">
            <Store type="StoreNum">1001</Store>
        </TxnCode>
        <SalesTime>2019-01-01-07:00</SalesTime>
        <SaleAmount>10</SaleAmount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <TxnCode Description="Store2">
            <Store type="StoreNum">1002</Store>
        </TxnCode>
        <SalesTime>2019-01-01-08:00</SalesTime>
        <SaleAmount>11</SaleAmount>
    </Transaction>
</Item_Entry>
<Item_Entry>
    <Item_group>
        <Item_Name>Name2</Item_Name>
        <Item_ID>0002</Item_ID>
        <Sale_Date>2019-01-02-00:00</Sale_Date>
    </Item_group>
    <Transaction>
        <TxnCode Description="Store3">
            <Store type="StoreNum">1003</Store>
        </TxnCode>
        <SalesTime>2019-01-02-09:00</SalesTime>
        <SaleAmount>12</SaleAmount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <TxnCode Description="Store4">
            <Store type="StoreNum">1004</Store>
        </TxnCode>
        <SalesTime>2019-01-02-10:00</SalesTime>
        <SaleAmount>13</SaleAmount>
    </Transaction>
 </Item_Entry>
</Item_Data>
```

Output:

```
Item_ID,Item_Name,Sale_Date,Store_Name,Store_Num,Sales_Time,Sale_Amount
0001,Name1,2019-01-01,Store1,1001,2019-01-01-07:00,10
0001,Name1,2019-01-01,Store2,1002,2019-01-01-08:00,11
0002,Name2,2019-01-02,Store3,1003,2019-01-01-09:00,12
0002,Name2,2019-01-02,Store4,1004,2019-01-01-10:00,13
```

Thanks,
Ug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XML to CSV or one "record" per line transformation I think (at least in XSLT 2/3) it is easy to push the relevant element representing a "record" or line to a template (i.e. in your case `<xsl:apply-templates select="//Transaction"/>`) and then in there to collect all data you want to output in the select of an `xsl:value-of` with the right `separator` e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text>Item_ID,Item_Name,Sale_Date,Store_Name,Store_Num,Sales_Time,Sale_Amount&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Transaction"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Transaction">
      <xsl:value-of select="../Item_group!(Item_ID, Item_Name, substring(Sale_Date, 1, 10)), */@* | .//*[not(*)]" separator=","/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuNX